# Debian 10 keeps asking for dhcp IP even with static ip configuration

Tags: networking, debian, static-ip

This is my interfaces file:

```
    # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
    # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

    source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

    # The loopback network interface
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    # The primary network interface

    auto ens3
    iface ens3 inet static
        address 192.168.3.202/24
        gateway 192.168.3.1
        dns-nameservers 192.168.3.200
```

Whenever I restart networking of do ifdown ens3 and ifup ens3, it still asks for a dhcp ip, and it gets a dhcp ip in addition to the static ip that is configured above. I'd rather it didnt and took the static ip only.

I don't have network manager installed.

Comment: Maybe there's some configuration in /etc/network/interfaces.d/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely dhcp queries aree caused by other configuration files.
Which dchp clients are installed?

man interfaces

> **The dhcp Method**
> This  method  may  be  used  to obtain an address via DHCP with any of the tools: **dhclient**, **pump**, **udhcpc**, **dhcpcd**. (They have been listed in
> their order of precedence.) If you have a complicated DHCP setup you should note that some of these clients  use  their  own  configuration
> files and do not obtain their configuration information via ifup.

Comment: I did:

    locate dhcp

And based on that output picked a file, and:

$ dpkg -S /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
isc-dhcp-client: /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

So I definitely have **isc-dhcp-client** installed. Based on some of the other matches above I'm pretty sure this is the only dhcp client installed. I tried uncommenting everything in dhclient.conf, but this did not change what I see

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following two things

```
    systemctl stop systemd-networkd
    systemctl disable systemd-networkd
    systemctl stop systemd-networkd.socket
    systemctl disable systemd-networkd.socket
```

Comment: Note that you have disabled the new network configuration method, and you are continuing to use the antiquated method. At most one of these methods should be enabledf.

Comment: I don't see that I need anything on offer than what I already get with the interfaces file. What's anitquated about it, apart from being mature?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to delete `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` , reboot and check what nmcli has to say about your interfaces. The tool called `nmcli` should be a part of a package called network-manager . Maybe make sure you have nmcli in the system, before you zap those legacy config files (or just move them into a backup location instead of deletion).

Comment: I already stated that I don't have network manager installed